# Making an element within a fixed div scroll over

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Building a site on twitter bootstrap 3.

I have a jumbotron with text, buttons, and a picture of myself. I want the picture of myself + the white div below to scroll up and over the jumbotron. I was able to get the white div to do so with z-index.

Visual representation of what I want

[image]

My problem is, how do I get the picture of myself to do the same? It's inheriting properties from the containing div, and I can't seem to override it.

1. The bottom of the image is being cut off by the white div, even if I put a higher z-index.
2. The image is fixed, doesn't move when I scroll.

I would provide a codepen, but it would take me a while to make. Here's the gist of the code:

```
<div class="jumbotron hero">
      <div class="container"> 
        <div class="row row-grid">
          <div class="col-lg-7 col-lg-offset-0 col-md-6 col-md-offset-0 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 text-center" id="header-text">
            <h1>Hi, I'm Giovanni.</h1>
            <h3>I'm a Marketing Professional and Public Speaking Coach</h3>
            <div class="btn-toolbar text-center" role="group" id="header-buttons">
              <a href="#marketing" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" id="primarycta">Marketing</a>
              <a href="#publicspeaking" class="btn btn-lg btn-warning" id="secondarycta">Public Speaking</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-5 col-lg-offset-0 col-md-6 col-md-offset-0 col-sm-12 col-sm-offset-0 col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 gio-image"><!--This is the image I want to move -->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

<div class="container" id="scrollover">

      <div class="row" id="marketing">
        <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1 text-center"><h1 class="bodyh1">Marketing</h1></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">

<!-- Etc... -->
```

CSS:

```
.hero {
  padding-top:140px;
  height:600px;
  min-height:400px;
  background-size:cover;
  overflow: visible;
  position: fixed;
  right:0;
  left:0;
  z-index:-1;
}

#scrollover {
  position: absolute;
  top: 70%;
  z-index:2;
  background: white;
  width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I'm not sure if my approach is the right way to do it, but it works.

I took

```
<div class="col-lg-5 col-lg-offset-0 col-md-6 col-md-offset-0 col-sm-12 col-sm-offset-0 col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 gio-image"><!--This is the image I want to move -->
</div>
```

and moved it in between the end of the jumbotron div and the beginning of the #scrollover container.

Then I used relative positioning to place it above and to the right of where it would naturally sit. I gave it a higher z-index so it would sit on top of both divs.

With this approach, I had to use some media queries to make sure it moved along with the rest of the page and didn't cover anything. But, overall, it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

try giving a `position:fixed` to your `.row` or `.row-grid`class.

You can also make it so that the `positiong:fixed` is added when you start scrolling down.

Check [this pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BdqpLx). I know it's not the prettiest css, but it should give you a general idea of what I mean

**EDIT**

Try giving your image a `background-attachment:fixed;`

```css
.image {
  background-image: url('https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/0e/9a/e3/1d/freedom-tower.jpg');
  background-size:100%;
  height:300px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

#other {
  width:50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="image">

</div>

<section id="other">
  What is Lorem Ipsum?
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</section>

<section id="other">
  What is Lorem Ipsum?
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</section>

<section id="other">
  What is Lorem Ipsum?
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</section>

<section id="other">
  What is Lorem Ipsum?
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</section>
```

Comment: Hmm, that's not quite what I'm looking for. I was able to do what I was asking about by putting the image in the second div, then using position: absolute and left/top to make it appear higher up. But that feels really hacky and it doesn't work with different browser sizes. Not sure how to proceed.

Comment: That's close, but on top of the image there needs to be another image, and that should scroll in sync with the white section. Look again at the image I put in the original post.

Comment: Is it possible to provide an example that is similar to what you want? It would help me to understand better.